# How do I get python's "in" operator to only yield true word matching, and not just substring matching?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, substring, string-matching

Here is the desired output:

```
"bacillus thurungensis" in "bacillus thurungensis"
TRUE

"bacillus thurungensis" in "Sentence containing bacillus thurungensis."
TRUE

"bacillus thurungensis" in "Subspecies bacillus thurungensis34"
FALSE

"bacillus thurungensis" in "bacillus thurungensis, bacillus genus"
TRUE

"bacillus thurungensis" in "Notbacillus thurungensis, must match word"
FALSE
```

Python typically thinks that any substring match is good, but I'm not looking for that. I want some regex or match operator to only yield true IF AND ONLY IF it sees the query as a separate word in the subject and not just a substring. How is this implimentable?

Comment: Use a regular expression, with the `\b` word boundary operator around the pattern.

Comment: You'll never get those exact code examples to work like that with ordinary strings, because that's not how `in` works on strings.  You'll have to use something else besides plain strings, or something else besides `in`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regex instead:

```
re.match(r"\bbacillus thurungensis\b", "bacillus thurungensis")
re.match(r"\bbacillus thurungensis\b", "Sentence containing bacillus thurungensis.")
re.match(r"\bbacillus thurungensis\b", "Subspecies bacillus thurungensis34")
```

And so on.

The `\b` is a [word boundary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). Also note the usage of the `r` in the string `r"..."`.

You can also use `compile` if you re going to use the regex over and over again:

```
import re
matcher = re.compile(r'\bbacillus thurungensis\b')
matcher.match("bacillus thurungensis")
# and so on
```

Comment: Very useful. TIL.

Comment: So this may sound like an odd request, but suppose instead of the string " bacillus thurungensis", I had a set of thousands of terms that I needed to check to see if that term is apart of the query string in question. This is unfortunately really slow. I'm doing 
`for i in theSet: `
    
    `c = re.compile(r'\b'+re.escape(i)+r'\b') `
    
    `if re.search(c, "query string")`

And moreover, I have a a thousand query strings to process. It's taking days to go though. is there  a way to speed it up? ( sorry I cant get the indentation to work on stackoveflow. It's not responding)

Comment: Helpful answer. Just note that the original poster probably wants re.search() instead of re.match(). re.search() will return true if the expression matches anywhere in the string whereas re.match() only matches the beginning of the string. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Comment: Thanks @dleng for your comment, feel free to upvote the answer.